# How to use sqlite_prepare_statement to InsertData in Sqlite Database in iphone application

Tags: iphone, sqlite

```
-(void)insertDataImage_ID:(NSInteger)ID ImageName:(NSString*)Image Bookmark:(NSString*)Title
{
    [self checkAndCreateDB];

    sqlite3 *database;

    if (sqlite3_open([DBPath UTF8String], &database)==SQLITE_OK) {

        NSString *statement;
        sqlite3_stmt *compliedstatement;
        statement =[[NSString alloc]  initWithFormat:@"insert into tblBookMark values(%d, '%@' , '%@')", ID,Image, Title ];

        statement = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat :@"select * from tblBookMark"];
        NSLog(@"T-1");

        const char *sqlstatement = [statement UTF8String];

        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlstatement, -1, &compliedstatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

            NSLog(@"T-2");
            if (SQLITE_DONE!=sqlite3_step(compliedstatement)) {

                NSLog(@"T-3");

                NSAssert1 (0,@"Error by inserting '%s'",sqlite3_errmsg(database));

                UIAlertView *AlertOK=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error !" message:@"Error by inserting" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes",nil];
                [AlertOK show];
                [AlertOK release];
            }
            NSLog(@"T-4");
            sqlite3_finalize(compliedstatement);
        }
        NSLog(@"T-5");
    }
    sqlite3_close(database);
    NSLog(@"T-6");

}
```

What is wrong in this code. It not showing any error but it

if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlstatement, -1, &compliedstatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)

Code flow is not entering in this line can any one help me to identify the error or suggest me solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code

```
static sqlite3_stmt *insertStmt = nil;

if(insertStmt == nil) 
{
    insertSql = "INSERT INTO Loginchk (uname,password) VALUES(?,?)";
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, insertSql, -1, &insertStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating insert statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
}

sqlite3_bind_text(insertStmt, 1, [Gunameq UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
sqlite3_bind_text(insertStmt, 2, [Gpassq UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(insertStmt))
    NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
else
    NSLog("Inserted");
//Reset the add statement.
sqlite3_reset(insertStmt);
insertStmt = nil;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not doing any error checking at all, no wonder you don't know what's going wrong!

Take a look at the sqlite 3 [error codes](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_abort.html). If the error is not SQLITE_OK, what is it?

```
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlstatement, -1, &compliedstatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
   ...
} else {
    NSLog(@"%i - %@", sqlite3_errcode(database), sqlite3_errmsg(database));
}
```

Comment: NSLog(@"Error Message -  %@", sqlite3_errmsg(database));          This code is returning 1. 
   
NSLog(@"Error Code - %i", sqlite3_errcode(database));            and it's gets down the application.

Comment: Take a look here : http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_abort.html - error code 1 means "SQL error or missing database" ?

Answer (score 1):

fix your query..."INSERT INTO tblBookMark (field1,field2) VALUES("","")";